# I am trying to do write a prime # program in C++

Tags: c++

I need to make a program that passes a user number to a bool function that will return a `bool` response if the number is a prime number or not and then have the program display if the number is prime or not. 
This is what I have and I am totally stuck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

//Declare return function
bool isPrime(int);


//Declare constant
const int PRIME=2;

int main()
{
    //Declare local variable to store user number
    int user_num;
    //Declare local variable to store result
    bool result;
    //Declare variable to hold return
    bool status;

    //Request number from user
    cout << "Please enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> user_num;

    //Call function isPrime
    bool isPrime(int user_num);

    if (status==true)
        cout << user_num << "is prime" << endl;
    else
        cout << user_num << "is not prime" << endl;

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;

} //end main

//Define bool function
bool isPrime(int number)
{
    bool status;

    double num_1=sqrt(number);

    for (int i=2;i<=num_1;++i)
        if(!(number%i))
            status=false;
        else
            status=true;
    return status;

}//End bool function
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
bool isPrime(int user_num);
```

to read

```
status = isPrime(user_num);
```

What you were doing there is declaring the function and not calling it.

You will need to move the function above the main function, or actually add

```
bool isPrime(int user_num);
```

above the main function or just before you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to consider the loop within isPrime. If you find a divisor, then return false immediately. At the moment, you will overwrite your result variable many times and only return the final test.